# Autocomplete loading blank data while trying to fill multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, autocomplete

Trying to use autocomplete to select a value and fill in multiple fields.

Getting small blank lines on autocomplete and search stops when typing.

I believe the problem is with
***.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem*** or unsupported jquery. Reference this [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Wz7Vy/) code, my code works on fiddler but not on my project. Not sure whats causing the issue.

Using asp core 3.1 and returning the same json as one below(projects)

> Javascript

```
 $(function() {
  var projects = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Service 1",
      "price":250.00,
      "quantity":1,
      "decription":"some stuff"
   },

   {"id":2,
      "name":"Service 2",
      "price":250.00,
      "quantity":1,
      "decription":"more stuff"
   },

   {"id":3,
      "name":"Service 3",
      "price":50.00,
      "quantity":1,
      "decription":"extra stuff"
   }
  ]
 
    $(".order_name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $(".order_name").val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(".price").val(ui.item.price);
            $(".name").val(ui.item.name);
            $(".quantity").val(ui.item.quantity);
            $(".description").val(ui.item.decription);
            return false;
        }
    })
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li></li>')
                .append("<a id='" + item.name + "'>" + item.name + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
});
```

> HTML

```
<div>Search:</div>

Search: <input class="order_name" />
<br><br>

Price : <input type="text" class="price" /><br>
Quantity : <input type="text" class="quantity" /><br>
Description : <input type="text" class="description" />
```

Comment: Did you try using the same Jquery version that Fiddler use, on your local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI component: autocomplete with JSON objects as source, you might need to change some property names to "label" and "value " in which:

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will
> be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If
> just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you
> provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
> label.

Related Link: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Hence, in your case, you should change the "name" property to the "label" property.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" 
            ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            console.log("Start");
            var projects = [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "label": "Service 1",
                    "price": 250.00,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "decription": "some stuff"
                },

                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "label": "Service 2",
                    "price": 250.00,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "decription": "more stuff"
                },

                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "label": "Service 3",
                    "price": 50.00,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "decription": "extra stuff"
                }
            ];

            $(".order_name").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: projects,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".order_name").val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".price").val(ui.item.price);
                    $(".name").val(ui.item.label);
                    $(".quantity").val(ui.item.quantity);
                    $(".description").val(ui.item.decription);
                    console.log("select");
                    return false;
                }
            })
                .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $('<li></li>')
                        .append("<a id='" + item.label + "'>" + item.label + "</a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
                };
        });
    </script>
```

Demo:

[image]